# Connecting a golang code with browser based vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, go, json-rpc

I am trying to connect a golang code with browser based vanilla JS in the browser using json-rpc yet I keep getting `TypeError: Failed to fetch`

Here is the code

The server in go

```
package main

import (
        "log"
        "net"
        "net/rpc"
        "net/rpc/jsonrpc"
)

type HelloService struct{}

func (p *HelloService) Hello(request string, reply *string) error {
        *reply = "Hello " + request
        return nil
}

func main() {
        rpc.RegisterName("HelloService", new(HelloService))
        listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":1234")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("ListenTCP error: ", err)
        }
        for {
                conn, err := listener.Accept()
                if err != nil {
                        log.Fatal("Accept error: ", err)
                }
                log.Printf("New connection: %+v\n", conn.RemoteAddr())
                go jsonrpc.ServeConn(conn)
        }
}
```

The client in the browser client.html

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Fetch a file to change this text.</p>
<script>

fetch('http://127.0.0.1:1234/rpc/v1', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      jsonrpc: '1.0',
      method: `HelloService.Hello`,
      params: ["popcontent"],//[],
      id: "jsonrpc"
    })
  })
.then((response) => {
  if (response.ok) {
    return response.json();
  }
  throw new Error('Something went wrong');
})
.then((responseJson) => {
  console.log("app :",error)
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log("app error:",error)
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can I even connect JS code with go code locally?
If I can run both locally, how can I fix the code?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Post and, when a certain condition is met, initiate a TCP connection and feed the data into `conn.Call`.

for example

```golang
http.HandleFunc("/myrpc/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // check
    {
        // check Method
        if r.Method != http.MethodPost {
            http.Error(w, "Method not allowed", http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
            return
        }
        // check Content-Type
        // check Auth
        // ...
    }

    // Get user input
    var req RPCRequest
    {
        _ = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&req)
    }

    conn, _ := rpc.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:12345")
    defer conn.Close()

    var reply string
    if err := conn.Call(req.Method, req.Params, &reply); err != nil { // <--
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    // handle response
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    resultBytes, _ := json.Marshal(struct {
        Msg string
    }{
        reply,
    })
    
    _, _ = fmt.Fprintln(w, string(resultBytes))
})
```

---

### A Runable example

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "net/rpc"
    "os/exec"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

type RPCRequest struct {
    Method string
    Params json.RawMessage
    Id     int
}

type Arith int

func (t *Arith) Multiply(args *json.RawMessage, reply *string) error {
    para := struct {
        A int `json:"a"`
        B int `json:"b"`
    }{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal(*args, &para); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *reply = fmt.Sprintf("%d", para.A*para.B)
    return nil
}

func (t *Arith) unMarshal(args *json.RawMessage) (*struct{ A, B int }, error) {
    output := new(struct{ A, B int })
    err := json.Unmarshal(*args, output)
    return output, err
}

func (t *Arith) Add(args *json.RawMessage, reply *string) error {
    para, err := t.unMarshal(args)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *reply = fmt.Sprintf("%d", para.A+para.B)
    return nil
}

func NewRPCServer() (listener net.Listener, runFunc func()) {
    rpcServer := rpc.NewServer()
    // rpcServer.RegisterName("Arith", new(Arith)) // same as below
    if err := rpcServer.Register(new(Arith)); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    listener, _ = net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:0")
    log.Println("[RPC SERVER]", listener.Addr().String())
    runFunc = func() {
        for {
            conn, err := listener.Accept()
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("[listener.Accept]", err)
                return
            }

            go func(conn net.Conn) {
                defer func() {
                    if err = conn.Close(); err != nil && !strings.Contains(err.Error(), "use of closed network connection") {
                        log.Println(err)
                    }
                }()
                _ = conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(2 * time.Second))
                rpcServer.ServeConn(conn)
            }(conn)
        }
    }
    return listener, runFunc
}

var RPCServerAddr *string

func main() {
    listenerRPC, rpcServerRunFunc := NewRPCServer()
    defer func() {
        _ = listenerRPC.Close()
    }()
    go rpcServerRunFunc()

    RPCServerAddr = new(string)
    *RPCServerAddr = listenerRPC.Addr().String()
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/myrpc/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.Method != http.MethodPost {
            http.Error(w, "Method not allowed", http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
            return
        }
        if r.Header.Get("Content-Type") != "application/json" {
            http.Error(w, "content type error", http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        var req RPCRequest
        if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&req); err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        conn, err := rpc.Dial("tcp", *RPCServerAddr)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }
        defer func() {
            _ = conn.Close()
        }()

        var reply string
        if err = conn.Call(req.Method, req.Params, &reply); err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        // handle response
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        resultBytes, _ := json.Marshal(struct {
            Msg   string
        }{
            reply,
        })
        if _, err = fmt.Fprintln(w, string(resultBytes)); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    })
    mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "index.html")
    })

    server := http.Server{Addr: "127.0.0.1:0", Handler: mux}
    listener, _ := net.Listen("tcp", server.Addr)
    log.Println("[Addr]:", listener.Addr())

    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        // help you open the browser automatically.
        go func() {
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            if err := exec.Command("rundll32", "url.dll,FileProtocolHandler", "http://"+listener.Addr().String()).Start(); err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
        }()
    }
    _ = server.Serve(listener)
}
```

index.html

```html
<h2>TEST RPC</h2>
<div></div>
<script type="module">
  async function rpcCall(method, params) {
    return fetch(location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname + (location.port ? ":" + location.port : "") +
      "/myrpc/", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        method,
        params,
        id: 0
      })
    })
      .then(response => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(result => {
        return result
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error.message)
      })
  }

  
  const aa = await rpcCall(Arith.Multiply", {a: 2, b: 3})
  console.log(aa);
  

  // more test
  [
    ["Arith.Multiply", {a: 2, b: 3}],
    ["Arith.Add", {a: 2, b: 3}],
  ].forEach(async ([method, params]) => {
    const val = await rpcCall(method, params)
    document.querySelector("div").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(val, null, 2) + "<br>"
  })
</script>
```